# Find $E(Y\mid X)$ given the original relationship

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Given $Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X + \beta_2Z + u$ and $E[u\mid X,Z] = 0$, what is $E[Y\mid X]$?

I've got $E[Y\mid X] = \beta_0 + \beta_1X + E[\beta_2Z\mid X]$. Can this be simplified further?

Comment: If $\beta_2$ is constant, i.e. not random, then you can change $\operatorname E(\beta_2 Z\mid X)$ to $\beta_2 \operatorname E(Z\mid X). \qquad$

Comment: Why $\mathbb{E}(u~|~X) = 0$?